# Conditionally loading multiple fields with multiselect with Caldera Forms for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, forms

Good day,

I've been looking around for a solution to my problem, but could not find it documented anywhere. Feel free to link to another thread if useful.

I'm building a form on Wordpress using Caldera Forms. In this form, I have a multiselect dropdown for which each selection should show dynamically an extra field. Unfortunately, I cannot load more than one conditional field when selecting multiple values. It will only load the first field populated by the condition of my first selection.

Try it out:

1. Open https://34.95.27.135/test-caldera/
2. On the "Role" field, select "Software Engineer"
3. This should populate a "Top Skills" field
4. On the "Top Skills" field, if you autocomplete ANY of the options, the first condition is met and you will see the right field for it
5. Selecting more options from the "Top Skills" field should be populating other fields, but instead, it flicks in the view and then only shows the first met conditional field.

Anyone has had this issue? Was there anything special to do on the Conditions tab to make it work as intended?

You may Import this form by importing this JSON:

`{"_last_updated":"Sun, 19 Jan 2020 23:23:23 +0000","ID":"CF5e213a11b5adc","cf_version":"1.8.9","name":"Career Matrix","scroll_top":0,"success":"Form has been successfully submitted. Thank you.\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t","db_support":1,"pinned":0,"hide_form":1,"check_honey":1,"avatar_field":"","form_ajax":1,"custom_callback":"","layout_grid":{"fields":{"fld_97450":"1:1","fld_5750655":"1:1","fld_4465116":"1:1","fld_2852708":"1:1"},"structure":"12"},"fields":{"fld_97450":{"ID":"fld_97450","type":"filtered_select2","label":"Top Skills","slug":"your_top_skills_software_engineer","conditions":{"type":"con_9081220263929126"},"required":1,"caption":"Select your top skills.","config":{"custom_class":"","placeholder":"","multi":1,"color":"#5b9dd9","border":"#4b8dc9","default_option":"","auto_type":"","taxonomy":"category","post_type":"post","value_field":"name","orderby_tax":"name","orderby_post":"name","order":"ASC","default":"","show_values":1,"option":{"opt2039319":{"calc_value":"x","value":"x","label":"x"},"opt2036344":{"calc_value":"y","value":"y","label":"y"},"opt2092176":{"calc_value":"z","value":"z","label":"z"}},"email_identifier":0,"personally_identifying":0}},"fld_4465116":{"ID":"fld_4465116","type":"star_rating","label":"z Proficiency","slug":"z_proficiency","conditions":{"type":"con_4202235771498248"},"caption":"Rate your z proficiency","config":{"custom_class":"","default":"","number":5,"type":"star","size":13,"space":3,"color":"#FFAA00","track_color":"#AFAFAF","email_identifier":0,"personally_identifying":0}},"fld_2852708":{"ID":"fld_2852708","type":"star_rating","label":"y Proficiency","slug":"y_proficiency","conditions":{"type":"con_6383484066940033"},"caption":"Rate your y proficiency","config":{"custom_class":"","default":"","number":5,"type":"star","size":13,"space":3,"color":"#FFAA00","track_color":"#AFAFAF","email_identifier":0,"personally_identifying":0}},"fld_5750655":{"ID":"fld_5750655","type":"star_rating","label":"x Proficiency","slug":"x_proficiency","conditions":{"type":"con_5108268722503233"},"caption":"Rate your x proficiency","config":{"custom_class":"","default":"","number":5,"type":"star","size":13,"space":3,"color":"#FFAA00","track_color":"#AFAFAF","email_identifier":0,"personally_identifying":0}}},"page_names":["Page 1"],"mailer":{"on_insert":1,"sender_name":"Caldera Forms Notification","sender_email":"dube25@gmail.com","reply_to":"","email_type":"html","recipients":"","bcc_to":"","email_subject":"Career Matrix","email_message":"{summary}"},"conditional_groups":{"conditions":{"con_5108268722503233":{"id":"con_5108268722503233","name":"SE x Skill","type":"show","fields":{"cl6611176254177354":"fld_97450"},"group":{"rw1073423041345211":{"cl6611176254177354":{"parent":"rw1073423041345211","field":"fld_97450","compare":"is","value":"opt2039319"}}}},"con_6383484066940033":{"id":"con_6383484066940033","name":"SE y Skill","type":"show","fields":{"cl4932869345780543":"fld_97450"},"group":{"rw2445485636298987":{"cl4932869345780543":{"parent":"rw2445485636298987","field":"fld_97450","compare":"is","value":"opt2036344"}}}},"con_4202235771498248":{"id":"con_4202235771498248","name":"SE z Skill","type":"show","group":{"rw3854064841859657":{"cl7317560418250427":{"parent":"rw3854064841859657","field":"fld_97450","compare":"is","value":"opt2092176"}}},"fields":{"cl7317560418250427":"fld_97450"}}}},"settings":{"responsive":{"break_point":"sm"}},"privacy_exporter_enabled":false,"version":"1.8.9","db_id":"19","type":"primary"}`

Thank you very much!